# Website loses google analytics referrer due to reload page

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, reload, traffic

I have come to a bit of a dead-end. Problem is that the first time our site loads, it needs to be reloaded once to get the correct width and height (from a cookie created in javascript) and show the appropriate images. I tried using location.reload(), or adding the meta refresh tag, but in both cases all incoming traffic from google is categorized as "direct" instead of "organic" which seems reasonable after looking at the documentation here https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3198398?hl=en

> **meta refresh and javascript based redirects** Non server-side invoked
>   redirects such as the meta refresh html tag or javascript
>   window.location methods may hide or obscure referrer information from
>   Analytics, therefore we don’t recommend using such methods on any page
>   that is likely to be a landing page

Does anyone have any ideas on how to implement that without the loss of referrer in google analytics? Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Eleni

Comment: What 'correct width and height' are you retrieving with the javascript cookie? It seems a bad strategy to directly reload a page on first visit, and I think that's the base of your problem?

Comment: I agree with Run CMD. Reloading a page immediately after first load is a horrible solution. Why not try to fix that instead?

Comment: Thank you for your comments, the problem is that this is a feature on our custom CMS which supports about 200 sites, so to change that feature requires a lot of refactoring in many sites as that reloading is used to get the correct images (in size).

Answer (score 0):

If you really have to stick with that scenario, I wouldn't reload at all. I'd respond to initial requests missing that cookie with a unique ID/session cookie. I'd send the bare minimum of the `<head>` (viewport meta, title, encoding) and a little snippet of JS, then immediately flush the output and sleep the server-side processing for a second. In the JS snippet, set the cookie and send a separate request back to the server either via XHR, or `new Image`, whatever works, and store it against that unique ID/session. Then when the initial page processing resumes, check your store for that data you just sent back. If it hasn't arrived, sleep again. Keep resuming, checking, & sleeping until you get the data or you hit a time out (5 seconds?) and fall back to a default.

It's fragile, hacky and you'd have to ensure that nothing buffers that initial output that needs to execute, but the page only loads once.